# Random numbers mean and standard deviation Java

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a program that has a 50 number long list with random numbers between 1 and 50. I need to find the mean and the standard deviation of said list. I'm having trouble with adding all the random numbers together. 
This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { // Set to 50 as max number just for example
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 50).summaryStatistics();`

Comment: You did not add "random" number ^^ only all the ints from 1 to 50

Comment: use `Random.nextInt(50) + 1;` for random numbers

Comment: With the simplified for-loop, you can avoid such comments: // Set to 50 as max number just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@azro mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893271/random-numbers-mean-and-standard-deviation-java#comment84792152_48893271) you are not using random ints from 1 to 50. You are just shuffling the numbers from 1 to 50 in the list.

If you really want a list of Random numbers from 1-50 then you can use [`Random::nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to get a random number like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    list.add(r.nextInt(50) + 1);
}
```

or even easier using [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) in Java 8:

```
List<Integer> list = new Random().ints(50,1,51) // generate 50 random numbers from 1 inclusive to 51 exclusive
        .boxed()                                // box each int
        .collect(Collectors.toList());          // get a list with the numbers
```

Comment: Thanks, to both of you, I completely did not realize I was doing that. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues I see with the code. It sounds like you're attempting to add 50 random numbers to a list. What your above code actually does is add the numbers 1:50 (inclusive) to a list, and then randomly shuffle the order of those numbers in the list. You will still have non-random numbers (all the numbers 1:50 will still be in the list, just in a random order).

What you should be doing is randomly generating the numbers and then adding them to the list. For example:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int upperBound = 50;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int randInt = rand.nextInt(upperBound) + 1;
        list.add(randInt);
        sum += randInt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about naming conventions. Does mean mean average? Sum divided by count?

```
Random random = new Random ();
int[] ia = IntStream.generate (()-> random.nextInt (50)).limit (50).toArray();
// ia wieder zu Stream machen? 
IntStream is = IntStream.of (ia);
double avg = is.summaryStatistics().getAverage()
// indeed, summaryStatistics exists.
// Expression value is: 
// IntSummaryStatistics{count=50, sum=1159, min=0, average=23,180000, max=47}
// but no stddev 

double stddev (int[] l, double avg) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (double d : l) {
        double xd = d - avg;
        sum += xd * xd;
    }
    return sum;
}
double std = stddev (ia, avg);
```

A different way, working with mapToDouble:

```
is = IntStream.of (ia);
double qabw (int i, double avg) {
  double abw = 1.0 * i - avg;
  double q = abw * abw;
  return q;
}
DoubleStream ds = is.mapToDouble(i-> qabw (i, avg));
double qsum ds.sum ();
```

I'm pretty fresh to the stream thing. It should be possible to feed the function stddev, which is, btw., incomplete, into a stream.

On the other side, by summaryStatistics().getAverage(), the stream is consumed and gone. So I have to store the values in an Array, for example, first, and then recreate a stream from the array.

Pretty complicated.

However, I think we need a Math.sqrt in the end for a correct value, and/or a division by count, so the mathematical part needs surely correction.

For improvement on working with streams: you're welcome.